# How do i append a list with new data?

Tags: python, list

I've read information from a csv file and converted it into a list of lists in python as follows:

```
[['a', '1', '2', '3'],
['b', '7', '8', '1'],
['c', '0', '10', '1'],
['d', '7', '8', '3'],
['e', '9', '8', '2']]
```

I then get a new input for the list containing `d`. The new value is `5`.
Knowing which element to edit I just want to change the last element contained in the `d`-list and replace this by the new value (replace `3` with `5`).

So I want to find the sublist containing `d` in the list and edit it as desired giving:

```
[['a', '1', '2', '3'],
['b', '7', '8', '1'],
['c', '0', '10', '1'],
['d', '8', '3', '5'],
['e', '9', '8', '2']]
```

Removing the first number and adding the new number:

```
import csv, re

name = input("Name: ").title()
data = [name]
for x in range(1,4):
    score = int(input("What score? "))
    data.append(score)
form = input("What form: 1,2 or 3? ")

print(data)

with open('{}.csv'.format(form), 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
    wr = csv.writer(csvfile)
    wr.writerow(data)

f = open('{}.csv'.format(form))
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

newlist = []

for row in csv_f:
    newlist.append(row[0:4])

print(newlist)
```

Comment: If you want to add to a list, you use `append`, as you have already shown. What's the question? How to get a reference to the list again once you've already iterated past it?

Comment: I want to change the data associated with 'name'

Comment: OK, use a dictionary instead of a list, but what is really misleading is the `least recent entry` bit

Comment: if name has 1 2 3 and i receive 5, i want to change it to 'name 2 3 5' by appending the list

Comment: I can search for the name within the list by entering: 'if name in list: ' but then i dont know how to append the data associated with it

Comment: You're still not making much sense. Pynchia is probably right. You should be using a dict for this that maps to lists. If you "receive" (whatever that means) a 5 that you know (however you know) goes with some name, then you `my_dict_of_names['name_in_question'].append(5)` or whatever. That assumes there's already a list present there in the dict, so you might catch an `AttributeError` if you think there won't be or else use a [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) there.

Comment: i dont want to add the 5 to the series of numbers, i want to remove the oldest number and add the '5'

Comment: I want to find the name in the dictionary------then append the list associated with the name

Comment: Then `pop()` first? Have you tried anything based on the new suggestions you're getting or are you just going to keep commenting and not clarifying your question until someone hopefully gives you a nice long code answer you can copy and paste?

Comment: I am trying to be as clear as possible, sorry

Comment: @pman: You're using a list of lists. Not a dictionary as you state in your question. Does this list of lists changes during the program execution? Where do you get your new data `-5` from? On which conditions do you want to find the list to change? You said you want to change the list containing `d`. However, on which criteria is that the element to change? Additionally, I am still not understanding which data comes from which source. For sure, we could solve your problem, but this would do the trick since you should understand what to do in order to proceed with further programming...

Comment: 1) You probably *should* be using a dict, and 2) This would be much easier to assist if you would show the code you're currently using, in a minimal, self-contained example.

Comment: @pman: Are you able to read the csv-files as you like or do you get the list of lists from someone else. If you have access to the csv-files a short snippet showing some (anonymised if necessary) sample data would be great. As far as I get it your task consists of different parts: 1) read csv-file 2) get a input (form which source ever, please clarify) 3) change data based on a given criterion and input data (please clarify criterion).

Comment: I've posted my code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this solves your problem

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

with open("file.csv") as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f)
    names = defaultdict(list)
    for row in csvfile:
        curname = row[0]
        new_nums = row[1:4]
        name_nums = names.get(curname)
        if name_nums:
            del name_nums[:len(new_nums)]
        names[curname].extend(new_nums)

print(names)
```

which, with an input file of

```
John,1,2,3
Mary,1,2,3
John,4,5
```

produces a `defaultdict` containing

```
{
 'John': ['3', '4', '5'],
 'Mary': ['1', '2', '3']
}
```

As pointed out in the comments below, here is an alternative which produces a plain dictionary

```
import csv

with open("file.csv") as f:
    csvfile = csv.reader(f)
    names = dict()
    for row in csvfile:
        curname = row[0]  # get the name on first col
        new_nums = row[1:4]  # get the values as a list
        name_nums = names.get(curname)  # get the stored values for the name
        if name_nums:  # true when the name had been encountered already
            del name_nums[:len(new_nums)]  # pop as many values as the new ones
            name_nums.extend(new_nums)  # append the new values
        else:
            names[curname] = new_nums  # new name so just add it to the dict

print(names)
```

Note: as you can see from the input data, the given solutions work for any given number of new values (up to three as specified, but you can change it), not just one (i.e. `5` in your example)

Comment: Is there a special reason for using a `defaultdict` instead of a `dict`?

Comment: @albert, default dict allows you to call `.extend` on any key and it would initiate a list if there is no value currently at that key. better since you dont need to check and initialize manually

Comment: When i print(names) it keeps printing defaultdict(<class 'list'> as well

Comment: Could you add comments to your code so i can see what each line does please

Comment: see my edit if you want to use a plain dictionary. There would be no difference if all you need to do is to iterate on its items.

Comment: Thank you very much Pynchia, but please could you tell me what each line does please

Comment: I have added comments now, check it out :)

Comment: What does 'pop' mean?

Comment: del name_nums[:len(new_scores)] - could you explain what del and :len do

Comment: `pop` has several meanings, I used it because lists have such a method to remove items from them (please see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html))

Comment: `del` deletes a name/object, in this case it removes N elements from the list, where N is the [length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) of the list containing the newly found values (i.e. how many new values followed the name)

Comment: You havn't used the pop function though...

Comment: no, I just used the word as in plain English (e.g. you pop the cap of a bottle), the actual code uses `del`. Think of the verb 'pop' as 'remove'

Comment: so, is it working at all? Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: It all works, i just want to know what line means what and not just copy and paste the code without learning

Comment: no problem whatsoever, I just wasn't sure the problem had been solved. You are doing the right thing to ask for details on unclear points. Thank you for accepting my answer.

Comment: Keep getting this error for some reason: IndexError: list index out of range for when name = row[0]

Comment: The input file may have an empty row